# Expression that means 'things that are not tied with each other together'

Tags: phrase-request

> I enjoy exploring things that are not tied with each other together.

I want to express that I like taking things that are completely different from the first glance and finding abstract laws for explaining them in general. Maybe from the standpoint that's completely different from the one widely used presently.

This sentence is in the context of explaining my personality to an acquaintance. So it's better off making it more informal.

Comment: What's an "equenty"?

Comment: If you have a specific concern with this question, we can help you with that but we are not here for proofreading or to write content for you. Is your sentence *understandable*, yes... is it written correctly, not really... could it be written better, certainly... but there are dozens of ways to rewrite this sentence and it depends on your personal writing style.

Comment: @Catija I think this is a request for an expression, not proof-reading. I know it's worded as a "is this is correct?" type question, but there's quite a bit of explanation of what he is trying to express, and it's not easy to find an expression like that in a dictionary.

Comment: I enjoy exploring ideas that are apparently unrelated to each other. And yes, what is an equenty? :)

Comment: @ColleenV That's certainly a way to interpret the question, sure... But as you can see from comments and answers here... there are many different ways to phrase this and there's no one "right" answer... this isn't something we have an idiom for.

Comment: @Catija When it comes to word and phrase requests, there isn't one right answer, but there are [good subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) that are on-topic. There are [plenty of highly rated questions in the phrase-request tag](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request?sort=votes) with 5 or more answers. Just because there are a lot of answers folks could suggest doesn't mean this is an unanswerable question.

Comment: @Catija acquenties, like comrads. is it incorrect?

Comment: Acquaintances? These are generally people you know but are not particularly close friends with.

Answer (score 4):

"I enjoy exploring things that are seemingly disparate in nature."

I think this captures the essence of what you want, but I would follow it up with examples.

"I enjoy exploring things that are seemingly disparate in nature. Such as chemistry and French cooking."

Comment: *Disparate* was my best answer after thinking for about 500ms, too.

Answer (score 2):

> I enjoy exploring things that are not tied with each other together.

This sentence might be improved by rephrasing it as StoneyB has in his comment:

> "I enjoy exploring the links between things that don't seem to be related." -StoneyB

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy finding hidden connections in unexpected places.